# How can I defer a nested state / templateUrl load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a nested ui router state (a ui-view within a ui-view) - How would I go about defering the load of only the child state?

The preferred scenario would have the child state simply waiting for an external API to load before loading it's own templateUrl, then triggering some task once it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

There are `resolve`s in ui-router that let's you do this, here's the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve).
You can use the resolve to wait for a data to be loaded before the state is navigated to

Comment: thanks for the reply @user2773086 - I've been working with resolves for several hours and have yet to understand how to accomplish this. Have any  specific suggestions or examples?

Comment: make sure you are familiar with promises first, so you can wait for the response of your external API to be loaded, before telling the resolve that it is finished.

Comment: or, try returning the promise that your API call gives